# want to create select box with multiple="multiple" attribute

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile 1.1 css and want to built a select box with multiple="multiple" attribute. I also tried so many things to change select box with multiple="multiple" attribute. But failed to convert it is  giving drop down as always even if i write select box like this given below so please suggest how can i go for select box with this attribute.

```
<select class="styled" name="purpose-" id="someID" onchange = "go()" multiple="multiple">
                  <option value="000"> Select </option>
                  <option value="008">1 </option>
                  <option value="012">2 </option>
</select>
```

after that it is giving select box like this
[image]

but i want to like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<select class="styled" name="purpose-" id="someID" onchange = "go()" multiple="multiple" size="9">
                  <option value="000"> Select </option>
                  <option value="008">1 </option>
                  <option value="012">2 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "*Note that the native menus don't support multiple selection via the
>   multiple="multiple" attribute. If this feature is needed, we recommend
>   using custom menus.*" [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html)

**Option to use custom menus**

*You can optionally use custom-styled select menus instead of the native versions. This adds the ability to theme the menu to better match the look and feel of your site and provides visual consistency across platforms. **In addition, it supports multiple selection**, restores missing functionality on certain platforms such as optgroup support on Android, and adds an elegant way to handle placeholder values (explained below).*

***To use custom menus on a specific select**, just add the `data-native-menu="false"` attribute. Alternately, this can also programmatically set the select menu's nativeMenu configuration option to false in a callback bound to the mobileinit event to achieve the same effect. This will globally make all selects use the custom menu by default. The following must be included in the page after jQuery is loaded but before jQuery Mobile is loaded.*

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
    });
```

**Source :** http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html